# PostGIS error building with `make` in ./extensions: make[1]: *** No rule to make target

Tags: postgis, postgresql-extensions, source-code

Whenever I run `make` in extensions, I'm getting error.

```
make
for DIR in postgis  postgis_tiger_geocoder  postgis_topology address_standardizer; do \
    echo "---- Making all in ${DIR}"; \
    make -C "${DIR}" all || exit 1; \
done
---- Making all in postgis
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/extensions/postgis'
cp ../../doc/postgis_comments.sql sql_bits/postgis_comments.sql
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../../raster/rt_pg/rtpostgis_for_extension.sql', needed by 'sql_bits/rtpostgis.sql'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ecarroll/code/postgis/extensions/postgis'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first run,

```
make;
```

in root, then you can run `make` in `./extensions`